# Unlinked java jars after installing Groovy from CMD on Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, maven, ubuntu, groovy

I've installed Groovy using the apt-get:

`sudo apt-get install groovy`

Now, when looking in the dir of groovy, in the lib dire of it, I found it links to jars not found on my system:

```
$/usr/share/groovy/lib$ ls -lt
total 5360
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Mar 15  2012 ant.jar -> ../../java/ant.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Mar 15  2012 ant-junit.jar -> ../../java/ant-junit.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      27 Mar 15  2012 ant-launcher.jar -> ../../java/ant-launcher.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Mar 15  2012 antlr.jar -> ../../java/antlr.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      28 Mar 15  2012 asm3-analysis.jar -> ../../java/asm3-analysis.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      19 Mar 15  2012 asm3.jar -> ../../java/asm3.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Mar 15  2012 asm3-tree.jar -> ../../java/asm3-tree.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Mar 15  2012 asm3-util.jar -> ../../java/asm3-util.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Mar 15  2012 bsf.jar -> ../../java/bsf.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      26 Mar 15  2012 commons-cli.jar -> ../../java/commons-cli.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      30 Mar 15  2012 commons-logging.jar -> ../../java/commons-logging.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Mar 15  2012 ivy.jar -> ../../java/ivy.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Mar 15  2012 jansi.jar -> ../../java/jansi.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Mar 15  2012 jline.jar -> ../../java/jline.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      22 Mar 15  2012 jsp-api.jar -> ../../java/jsp-api.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      21 Mar 15  2012 junit4.jar -> ../../java/junit4.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      31 Mar 15  2012 mockobjects-core.jar -> ../../java/mockobjects-core.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      21 Mar 15  2012 regexp.jar -> ../../java/regexp.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      26 Mar 15  2012 servlet-api.jar -> ../../java/servlet-api.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      22 Mar 15  2012 xstream.jar -> ../../java/xstream.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5485687 Mar 15  2012 groovy-1.8.6.jar
```

->

```
$/usr/share/groovy/lib$ ls -lt ../../java/ant.jar
ls: cannot access ../../java/ant.jar: No such file or directory
```

I need to know:

1. Should I care about it?
2. I have a long time program in Java and I rarely install java apps (groovy, ant, maven) a system wide (using installer), so I need to understand how ubuntu install this apps system-wide. (I noticed /usr/share/java -> contains java libs, /usr/lib/jvm -> contains the java vm itself, /usr/share/maven-repo/ contains mvn repo)

Answer (score 1):

Ant is `suggested` by groovy package http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/groovy
It means groovy can work without it, but in some cases ant is useful with groovy

apt-get don't install suggested packages, that's why ant is not installed in your system and link is broken.

In general - you should not care about it until something is not work as expected.

Comment: Also, not sure why you're getting `groovy-1.8.6`, as this is quite old.  I am not on Ubuntu, and use [GVM](http://gvmtool.net) to install Groovy so I have no idea if this is something your end, or the package maintainers end :-/

Comment: I got your answer for the first question, but still need answer for second one.
Yea, I heared of GVM, the Groovy RVM. but since I start looking @ groovy, So I don't care too much.

Comment: I don't know much more that you written in your question, you can find some useful information [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Java/Packaging)